# Inserting missing values in EXCEL column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns of data in EXCEL. In one column, I have the time (say in hours), and in the second column, I have the stock price data in each time.

```
Time              stock price
09:00:00 AM            5
11:00:00 AM            6
12:00:00 PM            5
```

Note that the time 10:00:00 AM is missing here as there was no transaction at this time. But I need to insert 10:00:00 AM in the first column in a way that the second column will show blank in the corresponding row. So that the two columns will look like:

```
Time              stock price
09:00:00 AM            5
10:00:00 AM
11:00:00 AM            6
12:00:00 PM            5
```

I have thousands of days' data and many missing times like that so it is not possible to correct manually. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Answer (score 4):

You actually don't need to use VBA to solve your problem.

At first you need to create a column in your original sheet containing both date and time data (if your time column not yet contain date) - this column need to be just before column "stock price"

Then create a list of all times in a new sheet. e.g. put "01/01/2010 09:00:00 AM" in A2 then put `=A2+1/24` to A3 (adds one hour) and fill down the formula as necessary.

Formula in column B in the new worksheet (starting from B2): `=iferror(vlookup(a2,[oldsheet!columnOfDateTime:columnOfStockPrice],2,false),"")` This will give you all your current data, living blank cells where no data is available.

When you're done you can remove all the formula (copy all the data and paste to the same location just values) and delete the old sheet.

Tip: it's more easy to work with a lot of formula if you convert your range to list.

Comment: ......................Nice approach!